# How to compare string value in dataframe column and value in cell to create new dataframe based on multi value dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-value-dictionary

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id.1.value.1        id.2.value.2      id.1.question    id.2.value.2
TRUE                     FALSE             TRUE             TRUE
```

I want to create logic that scans the column names of the df and extracts the last number only from column names that have `value` in column name and compare the value in the cell of the column that contains `value` with following logic:

1. If value in column `value` equal `TRUE` then compare the last number in multi value dictionary
2. use second value in multi key dictionary to create dataframe column names

Example:

```
my_dict = {1: ('a', 'category'),2: ('b', 'category'),\
           3: ('c', 'category'),4:('d','category'),\
           5:('e','subcategory'),6:('f','subcategory'),\
           7:('g','subcategory'),8:('h','subcategory'),\
           9:('i','subcategory'),10:('j','subcategory'),\
           11:('k','subcategor'),12:('l','subcategory'),\
           13:('m','subcategory'),14:('n','subcategory'),\
           15:('o','subcategory'),16:('p','subcategory'),\
           17:('q','subcategory'),18:('r','subcategory'),\
           19:('s','subcategory'),20:('t','subcategory'),\
           21:('u','subcategory'),22:('v','subcategory'),\
           23:('w','subcategory'),24:('x','subcategory')

           }
```

If my current df looks likes this:

```
id.1.value.1        id.2.value.2      id.1.question    id.6.value.6
    TRUE                 FALSE             TRUE             TRUE
```

New df should look like this:

```
category    subcategory
a               f
```

Comment: Is your initial `DataFrame` always only one row?

Comment: yes the dataframe is created a from a submission via webhook. Every new submission is a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = df.columns
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name in names:    
    if ('value' in name) & df[name][0]:
        last_number = int(name[-1])
        key, value = my_dict[last_number]
        try:
            new_df[value][0] = list(new_df[value][0]) + [key]
        except:
            new_df[value] = [key]
```

Comment: For some reason `name` is pulling up column that doesnt even contain the word `value`. I have tried adding periods after and before `value` in the `IF` statement.

Comment: I confirmed in the `names` the columns with `value` is present

Comment: I think the issue is that the `if` statement is not iterating through the entire list and i think `df[name]` is referencing the scientific notation of the number in the column I want like so `0    1.542210e+12
Name: data.answers.1542213646975.itemId, dtype: float64`

I used 1,2,3 as examples

Comment: I changed  `names = df.columns`  to `names = df.columns.values`. Got error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'numpy.float64'`

Comment: Ignore the above error: I changed  `names = df.columns`  to `names = df.columns.values` and changed `&` to `and`. Which picks up the right column. However `last_number` is only getting the last digit of the entire number. Full column name is: `data.answers.0987654321.value.1234567890` as an example. I want the entire number after `value` to compare in the dict

Comment: changed `if ('value' in name) & df[name][0]:
        last_number = int(name[-1])` to `if ('value' in name) and df[name][0]:
        last_number = int(name[-13:])`

Answer (score 0):

Where df,

```
   id.1.value.1  id.2.value.2  id.1.question  id.6.value.6
0          True         False           True          True
```

Use:

```
i = df.loc[:,df.columns[df.iloc[0]]].filter(like='value').columns.str.split('.').str[-1].astype(int).tolist()

my_dict = {1: ('a', 'category'),2: ('b', 'category'),\
           3: ('c', 'category'),4:('d','category'),\
           5:('e','subcategory'),6:('f','subcategory'),\
           7:('g','subcategory'),8:('h','subcategory'),\
           9:('i','subcategory'),10:('j','subcategory'),\
           11:('k','subcategor'),12:('l','subcategory'),\
           13:('m','subcategory'),14:('n','subcategory'),\
           15:('o','subcategory'),16:('p','subcategory'),\
           17:('q','subcategory'),18:('r','subcategory'),\
           19:('s','subcategory'),20:('t','subcategory'),\
           21:('u','subcategory'),22:('v','subcategory'),\
           23:('w','subcategory'),24:('x','subcategory')}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')

df_out = df1.loc[i].set_index(1).T

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
1 category subcategory
0        a           f
```

Comment: for the `i` variable, i get error: `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`

I am only looking to extract the number after `value.`

Comment: Also how are you comparing the cell value if its `TRUE`?

Comment: Oh... I am using df.iloc[0]  the first row of your input data frame.  df.columns[df.iloc[0]] is the part where I am only selecting columns with the value of true in the dataframe.

Comment: but wouldnt '0'be the first row of the df? if not 0 what should it be?

Comment: I am using iloc which is integer location so integer location numerical 0.

Comment: If I dont use 0 what should I use? I tried 1 and -1

Comment: .iloc[0] works with any dataframe.   Index position start at zero, therefore all dataframes with a single row will have .iloc[0]   Now, if your True False values are on a different row, then you can use .loc and identify that row by the index label using .loc instead of by integer location with .iloc.  Your dataframe index could be 'A' 'B' 'C' and 'D'.  df.iloc[0] will still get the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

# get column names
for col in (list(df)):

    if "value" in col:

        try:
            # operate only in columns where a valid number is found
            value = df[col].rpartition('.')[:-1]

            # When df== True
            if df.loc[col,1]==True:
                new_df[my_dict[value][1]]= my_dict[value][0]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: For some reason `name` is pulling up column that doesnt even contain the word `value`. Also did you mean `df` instead of `df_value`?

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if the df was called 'df' :P @RustyShackleford could you try out my updated code?

Comment: i got no error with your code but it did not work. So not sure what was wrong. Below answer worked

Comment: @RustyShackleford I've updated the code, try now. Tell me what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
ans = [my_dict[int(x[-1])] for x in df1.where(df1.loc[:,['value' in x for x in df1.columns]]).dropna(axis=1)]
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({v: k for k, v in dict(ans).items()}, orient='index').T
```

Output:

```
  category subcategory
0        a           f
```

Comment: when I run the `ans` line I get error `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object`. I have confirmed the column with value is listed in the column headers for the df

Comment: well it runs on my workbook, so god knows what's the issue with your implementation